# Trying to pass a Comparator through the constructor of a HashSet

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

As I'mtrying to figure out how to use the `Comparator` correctly , I am trying to sort my `Employee`s in a `HashSet`. So I did this:

```
Set<Employee> EmployeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>((a,b)->a.getAge()-b.getAge());
```

As you can see, I tried to sorted it by age, but when I am using this lambda expression, it produces a compilation error , so I guess something isn't right here.

This is my `Employee` class:

```
class Employee {    
    String name;
    int age;
    // constructor, getters and setters
}
```

**Edit**:

With a PriorityQueue it works perfectly:

```
Queue<Employee> list = new PriorityQueue<Employee>((a,b)->a.getAge()-b.getAge());
```

Why is that?

Comment: "*... it makes an error...*" - What does that mean? Compilation error? Runtime error? Wrong order? Please be precise.

Comment: @Turing85 Pretty sure a compilation error is quite obvious there if the same code is in use. Just an opinion though.

Comment: @nullpointer yes, it is obvious if you know the ins and outs of the Java API. But not everyone does. Furthermore, the [on-topic site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clearly states that debug questions "*must include [...] a specific problem [...]*".

Comment: HashSets are unordered collections.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) which ensures an ordered `Set` based on the `Comparator`

```
Set<Employee> employeeSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getAge));
// (a, b) -> a.getAge() - b.getAge() >>> Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getAge
```

The [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html) on the other hand doesn't accept a `Comparator` within its constructor for initialization.

***Edit***:

```
Queue<Employee> list = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getAge));
```

works fine since, [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is again an ordered collection which accepts a `Comparator` in one of its constructors.

Comment: If still wondering, **ordered** and unordered collection is the key difference here.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, `HashSet` is an unordered set, and so it cannot take a comparator that provides a sort order. You might want to use a sorted set such as `TreeSet` instead.

```
    Set<Employee> employeeSet = new TreeSet<>((a,b)->a.getAge()-b.getAge());
```

A quick note on numeric comparisons. Using subtraction to compare int values is dangerous, as it can give incorrect results if the subtraction overflows. This won't occur with people's ages whose typical range won't result in overflow. But if somebody were to copy this code and apply it to different values, it might result in bugs. Instead, I recommend using the `Comparator` utility methods to construct the right comparison function:

```
    Set<Employee> employeeSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getAge));
```

This will indeed sort the employees by age. However...

```
    Employee terry = new Employee("Terry", 37);
    Employee kelly = new Employee("Kelly", 26);
    Employee brett = new Employee("Brett", 32);
    Employee chris = new Employee("Chris", 26);
    List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(terry, kelly, brett, chris);
    Set<Employee> employeeSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getAge));
    employeeSet.addAll(employeeList);
    System.out.println(employeeSet);

    [Employee{name=Kelly, age=26}, Employee{name=Brett, age=32}, Employee{name=Terry, age=37}]
```

We added four employees, but there are only three employees in the set! Also:

```
    System.out.println(employeeSet.contains(kelly)); // true
    System.out.println(employeeSet.contains(chris)); // true
```

How is this possible? The provided comparator is used not only for *ordering* but it is also used to determine *set membership*. Since Kelly and Chris have the same age, this comparator considers them equal, so only one of them ends up in the set.

You probably don't want to use a `TreeSet` to do sorting by values that can have duplicates, because that will cause items to be lost. There are a couple things you can do. One, you can put the employees into a list and then sort the list:

```
    employeeList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getAge));

    // before
    [Employee{name=Terry, age=37}, Employee{name=Kelly, age=26}, Employee{name=Brett, age=32}, Employee{name=Chris, age=26}]

    // after
    [Employee{name=Kelly, age=26}, Employee{name=Chris, age=26}, Employee{name=Brett, age=32}, Employee{name=Terry, age=37}]
```

Or, you can write a more complex comparator that differentiates between every element of the input data, so that no two are considered duplicate. In a realistic example, employees can have the same name, so we might also want to include comparison of something that is truly unique such as an employee ID. However, for this simple example we can just sort on the employee's name:

```
    Set<Employee> employeeSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getAge)
                                                        .thenComparing(Employee::getName));
```

When all the employees are added, the result is:

```
    [Employee{name=Chris, age=26}, Employee{name=Kelly, age=26}, Employee{name=Brett, age=32}, Employee{name=Terry, age=37}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Mechanically speaking, a `HashSet` does not rely on a `Comparator` or the `Comparable` interface to determine order or uniqueness; instead, it relies on the `hashCode` of the individual elements you place inside of it.

This is why you can't add it as a constructor parameter; it doesn't make any sense to try to insert into a **hash** map values which have a natural order.  Unless otherwise prescribed by the implementation of the set, sets are by default **unordered**; `HashSet` is an *unordered* implementation of a set.

The reason that `PriorityQueue` and `TreeMap` work with comparators and `Comparable` elements is due to the way they're structured. Both `PriorityQueue` and `TreeMap` order elements [in natural order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), so having a `Comparator` to drive that in the absence of your elements implementing `Comparable` can be desirable.  These data structures are *ordered*, so imposing custom ordering is a feature for these.

Comment: Edit: I got very confused here thinking this was C# but it's Java. Sorry @Makoto!

Comment: You lost @Simon_Weaver?  This is Java, not C#.